# How to change permission based on request.query_params in Django rest frameworks?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I merged together two views that almost does the same thing except the permission, I want to change permission based on: if *company* id is in the params. If not, it would use a simple **IsAuthenticated** class and also created a permission for **IsCompany**.

```
class FilesView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = FileSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    ...
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        if 'company' in self.request.query_params:
            # In this case I want the IsCompany Permission class
            return get_company_files(self)
        # Otherwise the regular one
        return get_personal_files(self)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [custom permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) at DRF documentations.

A little example:

```py
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsCompanyRequestBasedPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = '<description of your permission>'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if 'company' in self.request.query_params:
            # Make your decision.
```

And then add it to `permission_classes`. It would work just as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
class FilesView(ModelViewSet):
```

instead of

```
class FilesView(ListAPIView)
```

you can use get_serializer_class method which could help you
For example

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if "your statement":
        return "FirstSerializer"
    if "your statement":
        return "SecondSerializer"
```